# VSTS build definition organization ID error

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have problems defining build definition in VSTSting errors:

- Credential parameter can only be used with Organization ID credentials. For more information, please refer [for more information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=331007&clcid=0x409) about the difference between an organizational account and a Microsoft account.

There was an error with the Azure credentials used for deployment.

What should I do to successfully deploy?

Comment: 1). Could you please offer me more information about which instruction you're following to set up the build definition? 2) Can you show me one screenshot then I can better understand your scenario? 3). Which build definition you're using? Additionally, this link described the detailed steps on how to set up CI deployments in VSO: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/ . However, it seems not applied to your scenario.

Comment: 1) I created a custom build definitiom by STEPS: VS->Team Explorer-> Builds -> New build definition. I chose VS build to Azure web page and entered my Azure account details. However, running the build I get the said errors which suggest getting "organization account to azure". 2) I cannot upload a photo because I have to less reputation 3) Build definition I explained in part 1).  Thanks for the link, but that article is obsolete having in mind new version of Azure portal. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: My third question should be which build process template you're using? Is it the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml? Or you're working in the vNext build system which is described: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2015/04/29/deploying-an-azure-web-site-using-tfs-build-vnext.aspx

Comment: vNext build system as in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late maybe for you Dainius, but I've just had the same error message when setting up my Azure service endpoint with my username and password and trying to use the Deploy Step "[Azure Web App Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/deploy/azure-web-app-deployment)".

One solution I found if you don't have an Organization account is to use "Certificate Based" rather than "Credentials" when setting up your Azure service endpoint.  At the time of writing, to get your Management Certificate, hover over the help icon and follow the link "[publish settings file](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=vsserverexplorer&schemaversion=2.0)".  This should download a .publishsettings file.  Copy and paste the Management Certificate from within the file into the relevant VSO textbox.